# Piping a stream to S3 PutObject in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, compression

I am building an application where I need to dynamically generate a Dockerfile from a lambda, then compress it to a tar.gz file and upload to S3, all from within a lambda function. I am, however, getting the following error from S3:

```
"Error: NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented"
```

Here is my code:

```
const tar = require("tar");
const fs = require("fs");

const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");

const buildDockerFile = {
  stock: async (repository, tag, repositoryId) => {
    const input = `FROM ${repository}:${tag}`;
    const pass = new PassThrough();

    fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/Dockerfile", input);
    tar.c({ gzip: true }, ["/tmp/Dockerfile"]).pipe(pass);
    
    const params = {
      Body: pass,
      Bucket: process.env.DOCKER_IMAGES_BUCKET,
      Key: `${repositoryId}/${tag}/build-context.tar.gz`,
    };

    await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
  }
};
```

I am using a third-party library `node-tar` for creating the tar.gz file and I am utilizing lambda temp storage. I will really appreciate some assistance on the matter.

Comment: Do you need to stream it? Could you instead simply tar/gz the (tiny) Dockerfile onto the Lambda /tmp file system and then do a regular file upload from there to S3? Not to say that solving the streaming issue is not valuable, but is that the primary goal here.

Comment: I tried saving also the tar/gz file to the /tmp folder and creating a read stream and passing to S3. The file get's uploaded but is corrupted for some reason.

Comment: Just use `Body: fs.readFileSync('/tmp/build-context.tar.gz')` in params?

Answer (score 3):

After several hours, I was actually able to find a solution to my problem. AWS provided a library that really helps in situations like this - `@aws-sdk/lib-storage`.

Here is the full working version of my code:

```
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { Upload } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-storage");
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");
const tar = require("tar");
const fs = require("fs");

const s3 = new S3Client();

const uploadToS3 = ({ repositoryId, tag }) => {
  const pass = new PassThrough();

  const target = {
    Bucket: process.env.DOCKER_IMAGES_BUCKET,
    Key: `${repositoryId}/${tag}/context.tar.gz`,
    Body: pass,
  };

  return {
    stream: pass,
    promise: new Upload({ client: s3, params: target }),
  };
};

const buildDockerFile = {
  stock: async (repository, tag, repositoryId) => {
    const input = `FROM ${repository}:${tag}`;
    const { stream, promise } = uploadToS3({ repositoryId, tag });

    fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/Dockerfile", input);

    tar
      .c(
        {
          gzip: true,
          sync: true,
          cwd: "/tmp",
        },
        ["Dockerfile"]
      )
      .pipe(stream);

    await promise.done();
  },
};
```

I am posting this here just in case somebody else encounters that same problem with compressed files and S3.